# Approximating a fourth point with a weighted average between three points?

Tags: mathematics, interpolation

Given three points \$p_1,p_2,p_3\$, how would one approximate the best positive weights \$(u, v, w)\$ such that \$u+v+w = 1\$ and that the distance between the new \$up_0 + vp_1 + wp_2\$  from \$p_3\$ is minimal?

Basically, the enemy's unit is positioned between several "bases" on a 2d plainand it's easy to tell which is closest or even find the "weights" between two bases \$(t, 1-t)\$ to compute the relative fractions (eg. 0.3, 0.7). How does one find the optimal weights for three surrounding points?

Comment: Why do you want to find specifically points with `u+v+w = 1`, when you are interested in the distance/influence? Why not just compute/compare distances to said 3 points?

Comment: This is just chaining together two common operations: **1)** find the closest point to `p3` on the plane containing `p0p1p2` (hint: find the normal `n` to that plane, then your in-plane point `q = p3 - n * dot(n, p3 - p0)`) **2)** find the [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) of `q` within the triangle `p0p1p2`